# How to Return BadRequest with Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my api reponse i need to return BadRequest Response with Object which is given by user. I am using `IHttpActionResult` as return type. can any one try to help me.

**I have tried**

```
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{ 
   var Response = Method1();
   return BadRequest(Response);
}
```

But BadRequest doesn't accept the parameter.

Comment: return BadRequest(obj) ?

Comment: BadRequest doesn't accept the parameter

Comment: @Satheesh the accepted answer in the linked duplicate should be able to help solve your issue.

Comment: @Satheesh - it does - public virtual BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest([ActionResultObjectValue] object error);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Response.StatusCode = 400;
return Content("Something here");
```